# SQLCMD not printing result messages after first result returned 0 rows

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am running a few insert and update statements with sqlcmd into my sql-server DB. When the first statement returns 0 rows the output to the screen is only showing 0 rows affected and the output for the consecutive messages are not shown even tho they succeeded in the DB.

When the first statement is affecting one or more rows all the messages are shown. Even if a 0 rows affected statement is happening at a later stage in the script. Also tried using semi colons at the end of each statement. Tried with SET NOCOUNT ON. All to the same effect. None of the command line parameters of sqlcmd seemed to work either

Found this article: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d6c5e90c-0c74-4ab4-b883-7a5ac93c6220/messages-from-sqlcmd?forum=transactsql
Doesn't look like this is something they fixed. I am running on version 17.3.0000.1 from Linux. Also tried on older versions with no luck.

```
sqlcmd -S myserver,INST01 -i test.sql -d MyDB
```

here the content of my sql script:

```
UPDATE [MissionsDB].[dbo].[People_test] SET Name = 'TEST' WHERE 1=0;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[People_test] (Name) VALUES ('Peter2')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[People_test] (Name) VALUES ('Peter3')
UPDATE [dbo].[People_test] SET Name = 'Peter5' WHERE Name in ('Peter3','Peter1')
```

And this is the output:

```
(0 rows affected)
```

Nothing being displayed after that.

When I put the first insert statement to be executed not in first position then sqlcmd prints all the result messages to the screen.

Any advice on this?

Comment: Your script 

**INSERT INTO [dbo].[People_test] (Name) VALUES ('Peter1') WHERE 1=0;**

is incorrect
You can not put a Where with insert ... Values

Comment: updated the sql, still same effect.

Comment: I tried the same command, but in windows, As I don'h have Linus machine, it is showing the number of affected rows. I suggest that you run it under sql management studio with this way exec master..cp_cmdshell 'your sqlcmd command'

Comment: Is using a dummy `SELECT NULL` statement to artificially produce a result for your first statement an option? If the output messes up anything else, an alternative is `SELECT NULL a INTO #t` to have a statement that "affects rows".

Comment: good idea Jeroen. Works as expected now. But that way I will always have the 1 row affected in the first line. Not the ideal solution. Maybe a question for MS support after all?

Comment: Skipping the first line of the output unconditionally is also trivial (`tail -n +2`), but yes, obviously such workarounds should not be necessary in the first place and `sqlcmd` shouldn't be caring about how many rows the first statement affects.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think it was a legitimate bug in older versions of sqlcmd. Seems like it's been fixed now (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue. It turns out it was due to using an older version of sqlcmd. To see which version you're running, use:

```
sqlcmd -?
```

I'm not sure which version fixed this, but version 10.50.2500.0 had the problem you described, and version 15.0.1300.359 did not.